# Save submit variables without using Database?

Tags: php

Is it possible to save the input from a form just using php? So without using a Database ?

Current snaps of my code:

html

```
<form method="post" name = "post">
    <p><input type="text" name="api_key_send" value="" placeholder="api key sendcloud"></p>
```

php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

 $_SESSION['api_key_send'] = $_POST['api_key_send'];
```

This is the I way take the current input of the user and use it to execute rest of script. I want what the user inputs to stay remembered until new input overwrites it. Offcourse i know you can use a database for this but is that neccessary?

update:

it works but only when i put the right value as user over and over again. I want if you press the button the second time that it just remembers the previous input.

Trying to clarify:

My thought was that I could do something like this :

```
$_SESSION['api_key_send'] = $_POST['api_key_send'];
$var = $_POST['api_key_send']; <<<<
```

Comment: use cookies or session or you can write on file( in this no database is required).

Comment: Stay remembered for *how long*? Using session variables it'll just be until the session expires. There are no guarantees with cookies or local storage as the user can disable them. If you need that data to exist between sessions then you'll need some kind of persistent storage; a database is ideal. You *could* write it to the filesystem as a text or XML file, granted, but that's actually got more inherent problems than just using a database.

Comment: @CD001 Pretty clear answer, I wish until i submit something else.(how long)

Comment: baboizk @CD001 means that the approach you are using to save the details is incorrect.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala not necessarily - it depends on what the actual objective is here... I'm a little confused by *"until I submit something else"*; does that mean *until I submit something else during this session* (presumably overwriting the data with new data from the form) **or** *until I submit something else at some undefined point in the future* ? How persistent does the data need to be?

Comment: @luweiqi my initial thought was that i could store the session / post data in side a new variable $var . $var will stay the same value until someone restarts this session and updates everything over again. But Considering the answers it doesn't seem like you can make the $_session and $_post variable store the value inside a new $var and let it be.

Comment: @baboizk Yup, `$_SESSION` is *temporary*, if you need it to be *permanent*, you'll need to store it in a file or database

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala the undefined point in the future should be the correct line :)

Comment: @baboizk a normal `$var` is even more temporary than `$_SESSION`, it's destroyed as soon as PHP is done with it - if that's inside a function it'll be as soon as the function exits otherwise it's as soon as the script finishes running. It *sounds like* you're going to need persistent storage of some kind ... and a database is the most reliable way to go if that's the case.

Comment: @CD001 you'r right, Trying to learn new Things and never saw this type of question before. I thought maybe that it could be achieved. As you said also cookies are not reliable because you can disable cookies and that's also no persistent storage. Which also makes a DB easier then using cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SESSION` can be used for temporary storage and will be cleared by clearing browser data under most circumstances. *(Elaboration on exceptions below)*

If you use transparent session ids then that session can be picked up by anyone entering the SID in the address bar. The session is actually destroyed based on PHP's Garbage Collection settings (the session.gc_* parameters in php.ini) - even if you're using cookie-based sessions. If the user unsets their cookies the session is't necessarily destroyed it's just no longer picked up by that user. *(Credits to @CD001 for this elaboration)*

---

Using a variable (`$var`) is a even more temporary solution, it will get unset once the user closes the window.

```
$var = $_POST['api_key_send']; <<<<
```

---

Thus, for permanent storage, you'll need to use a database or save the input to a file.

Comment: What's the difference with your code and mine? to clarify my session_start() is on top of the page                                                     <?php
session_start();

Comment: @luweiqi `session_start();` had to be 1st line in the code and not inside `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

Comment: it works but only when i put the right value as user over and over again. I want if you press the button the second time that it just remembers the previous input.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Yup, edited post, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @luweiqi its not the correct way to store the data, using `sessions`. The data will go away once the session is expired.

Comment: @luweiqi thanks for the clear and proper explanation

Comment: *`$_SESSION` is temporary storage will be unset if the user clears his web data.* ... that's not strictly 100% accurate. If you use transparent session ids then that session can be picked up by anyone entering the SID in the address bar. The session is actually destroyed based on PHP's Garbage Collection settings (the `session.gc_*` parameters in php.ini) - even if you're using cookie-based sessions. If the user unsets their cookies the session is't necessarily destroyed it's just no longer picked up by that user.

Comment: @CD001 True, thanks for pointing out, will update the post :)

Comment: Not really necessary - in most practical instances you're fine... I can just be a bit of a stickler for accuracy sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

You could also employ [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), and keep the data in the end user's client.

There are two properties of `window`, accessible via javascript:

- window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
- window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Comment: learned something new here. Also not what I can use because it's not only browser related but thank you!